# Azure Functions - KafkaTrigger - Deserialize composite object with avro return null values on second level

Tags: java, apache-kafka, azure-functions, avro

I'am creating Azure Functions using KafkaTrigger to consume data from Kafka, where an Avro schema is registered. When i use dataType = "binary", i can deserialize the message, but I'm unable to get the message key, only value. When I use avroSchema = myAvro, I can get an object containing the key, but the data is in a malformed string format.

I need deserialize complex object. Ideal with use schema registry.

```
@KafkaTrigger(
    name = "kafkaMeetingTrigger",
    topic = "topicName",
    brokerList = "%BrokerList%",
    cardinality = Cardinality.ONE,
    sslCertificateLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    sslKeyLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    sslCaLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    protocol = BrokerProtocol.SSL,
    dataType = "binary",
    schemaRegistryUrl = "%SchemaRegistry%",
    consumerGroup="%ConsumerGroup%") byte[] kafkaEventData,
```

This return byte array with value from Kafka. Then I able to deserialize to my object, but key is lost.

```
@KafkaTrigger(
    name = "kafkaMeetingTrigger",
    topic = "topicName",
    brokerList = "%BrokerList%",
    cardinality = Cardinality.ONE,
    sslCertificateLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    sslKeyLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    sslCaLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    protocol = BrokerProtocol.SSL,
    avroSchema = avro,
    consumerGroup="%ConsumerGroup%") Meeting kafkaEventData
```

This return incomplete object.

```
{
"correlationId": "iaymjxnlpnocbe",
"meeting":
{
    "assistanceType": null,
    "attendanceType": null,
    "clients": null,
    "communicationType": null
},
"published": "2023-11-24T11:31:05.105Z",
"transactionId": "ipdsrntgklkvliyt"
```

}

Example of avro:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Meeting_keyDataChanged",
  "namespace": "cz.csas.avroschemas.meeting_keydatachanged.v03_02",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "correlationId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "meeting",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Meeting",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "assistanceType",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "attendanceType",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "clients",
            "type": [
              "null",
              {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "record",
                  "name": "Client",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "name": "clientType",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "isPrimary",
                      "type": "boolean"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "default": null
          },
       .........
    {
      "name": "published",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "transactionId",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
@KafkaTrigger(
   name = "kafkaMeetingTrigger",
   topic = "EVT.Meeting_keyDataChanged_v03_02",
   brokerList = "%BrokerList%",
   cardinality = Cardinality.ONE,
   sslCertificateLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
   sslKeyLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
   sslCaLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
   protocol = BrokerProtocol.SSL,
   avroSchema = avro,
   schemaRegistryUrl = "%SchemaRegistry%",
   consumerGroup="%ConsumerGroup%") ConsumerRecord<Object, Meeting> kafkaEventData
```

This return exception: Cannot evaluate org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord.toString()

```
@KafkaTrigger(
    name = "kafkaMeetingTrigger",
    topic = "EVT.Meeting_keyDataChanged_v03_02",
    brokerList = "%BrokerList%",
    cardinality = Cardinality.ONE,
    sslCertificateLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    sslKeyLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    sslCaLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    protocol = BrokerProtocol.SSL,
    dataType = "string",
    avroSchema = avro,
    schemaRegistryUrl = "%SchemaRegistry%",
    consumerGroup="%ConsumerGroup%") String kafkaEventData
```

This return String which contains data only for first level. Next level contains only schema.

```
{"correlationId":"iaymjxnlpnocbe","meeting":{"Schema":{"Fields":[{"Name":"assistanceType","aliases":null,"Aliases":null,"Pos":0,"Documentation":"Typ asistence na schuzce.","DefaultValue":null,"Ordering":2,"Schema":{"Schemas":[{"Name":"null","Tag":0,"Fullname":"null"},{"Name":"string","Tag":7,"Fullname":"string"}],"Count":2,"Name":"union","Tag":12,"Fullname":"union"}},{"Name":"attendanceType","aliases":null,"Aliases":null,"Pos":1,"Documentation":"Typ doprovodu na schuzce.","DefaultValue":null,"Ordering":2,"Schema":{"Schemas":[{"Name":"null","Tag":0,"Fullname":"null"},{"Name":"string","Tag":7,"Fullname":"string"}],"Count":2,"Name":"union","Tag":12,"Fullname":"union"}},{"Name":"clients","aliases":null,"Aliases":null,"Pos":2,"Documentation":null,"DefaultValue":null,"Ordering":2,"Schema":{"Schemas":[{"Name":"null","Tag":0,......
```

When I don't use avro I give whole object with key and offset, but Object can't deserialize.

```
@KafkaTrigger(
    name = "kafkaMeetingTrigger",
    topic = "EVT.Meeting_keyDataChanged_v03_02",
    brokerList = "%BrokerList%",
    cardinality = Cardinality.ONE,
    sslCertificateLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    sslKeyLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    sslCaLocation = "%KafkaCert%",
    protocol = BrokerProtocol.SSL,
    dataType = "string",
    schemaRegistryUrl = "%SchemaRegistry%",
    consumerGroup="%ConsumerGroup%") String kafkaEventData
```

Example of result

```
{
    "Offset": 323,
    "Partition": 0,
    "Topic": "EVT.Meeting_keyDataChanged_v03_02",
    "Timestamp": "2023-11-27T07:46:12.435Z",
    "Value": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\bE\u001ciaymjxnlpnocbe\u0002\u0016kbsdkmeyalo\u00022urhywvxlrixyuqhhmrioqvpxv\u0002\u0002<mcxbasjpxwfbjmogfdlmyucmtkiffpHnmysbemqgyeqnelyhjboneshwjufsulyfpfv\u0001\u0000\u0002.tslhjfloiepkmuneymnqbjc\u0002(fxjlobrtqoaymkfwurqm\u0002\brxsy��ȑ�c\u0000\u0002Bsqnsoblhpfkobciourcjtpwxrgqnvdtrq\u0002\u001ewwntnicjjvcsglu\u0002&sdpdptdflhjlkrhxlls\u00020msrqlxpjbdkkgbwsuslaeeql\u0002<nvttxsgwwlmgvtbhflbmdvtfceasvm\u0002Nakybxmgwxlapymnfymqytjwdqcwfipivsnmjpmi\u0002\u0002\bselt\bpmep\u0002:gcpxjxwrqtceoysrirqvdnllmhcdv\u0002\u001accbfdnjyrbtxi\u0004tr��ȑ�cBxouriawfhfevlthfcfikpuaarjxfmmwkl\u0002.gvoiukbrporvptduebdvucb\u0002\u0006xsp\b\u0002\u0002(mfiudurtxmiejnynnjis\u0002@qcohlkrkprlkuydljhpkilaxoxsvrrbg\u0002\u001anptiwyholnpfr\u0001@usyyfhyjfoyoaulsvnyjnxcqicfscbkl\u0002\u0002Hsgduxxraimgjsduecbgyvypeupuhmvuqcwkc\u0002\u001ehxhupdrenujqcrx\u00028khjhnbyjeihfkfrmkuuyepvxdhbv\u00016vijyhthrgatcjxqbimfslksnrti\u0002\u0002Hrbudwdqichgdgwwgnscljauphjclxbrjpmoe\u00024jxkknmcltpitgocsfdcrwjuvoc\u0002\bklpd\u0001Jkuwvteymnagdcjvtjwlnvktwjfqbncgpxbhnh\u0002\u0002Jjgsfdxrsujpbkdbewkuudtsdajvmexniuwpxu\u0002Fgerujewxkcnmexffsujlyibkbidnjxyiedr\u0002\u0000\u0001.bdfyrklhntdbknmuxvrgwjc\u0000��ȑ�c ipdsrntgklkvliyt",
    "Key": null,
    "Headers":
    []
}
```

Comment: What exactly is incomplete? What do you "malformed". Looks like every field is there from the schema. Everything in the meeting record has a default of null... Have you tried using `ConsumerRecord<K, Meeting>`?

Comment: When I use:

                  dataType = "string",
                    avroSchema = avro,
                    schemaRegistryUrl = "%SchemaRegistry%",
                    consumerGroup="%ConsumerGroup%") String kafkaEventData

I give String which contains data only for first level. Next level contains only schema.

{"correlationId":"iaymjxnlpnocbe","meeting":{"Schema":{"Fields":[{"Name":"assistanceType","aliases":null,"Aliases":null,"Pos":0,"Documentation":"Typ asistence na schuzce.","DefaultValue":null,"Ordering":2,"Schema":{"Schemas":[{"Name":"null","Tag":0,"Fullname":"null"},

Comment: When I use:

                   avroSchema = avro,
                    schemaRegistryUrl = "%SchemaRegistry%",
                    consumerGroup="%ConsumerGroup%") ConsumerRecord<Object, Meeting> kafkaEventData

I give exception:

Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord.toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I think it's working as documented... You'll need to contact Azure support to get anything different...

According to the documentation, if you use string, then you'll always get the whole record as json, and must manually deserialize using json first before you can process anything else.

If you don't want json, you can also supply datatype as binary, in which case, you'll still need to manually deserialize the data using Confluent deserializer class, but still, that may only be the value

When using avro datatype, you can only supply a schema for the value, not also a key, assuming it were Avro as well.

---

You can find an example here for getting the record headers and you'll have to do something similar to get the key

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension/blob/dev/samples/java/confluent/src/main/java/com/contoso/kafka/KafkaTriggerWithHeaders.java